# Differential calculus: Gradient and hessian local minimum point

Tags: optimization

Let the function defined on E = R$^2$ by J(x,y)=$x^2-xy +y^2+3x-2y+1$

Calculate the associated gradient and hessian? 
 Deduce, the value of a local mimi point is what a strict mimimum

So the gradiant is : $(2x-y+3,2y-x-2)$

$1) 2x-y=-3$ and   $2)  2y-x=3$ we can deduce 1) + 2) => y=0 $
and $
x=-1 $
or x=3/2$

J(x,y) -J(0,-1)==$x^2-xy +y^2+3x-2y+1-(1+3+1)=0 $

**I made a mistake**

Comment: You certainly did. A couple of them. What’s your question?

Comment: My question is to know if the  gradient and hessian is true and how to deduce, the value of a local mimi point is what a strict mimimum